# Loop through Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a data table like:

```
 DataTable dtAbsent = new DataTable();
 dtAbsent.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
 dtAbsent.Columns.Add("TypeOfLeave", typeof(string));
 dtAbsent.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(string));
```

And I am adding data to it like this:

```
dtAbsent.Rows.Add("2014-10-05', "H","Current");
```

So my final Datatable is:

```
     Date    |   TypeOfLeave  | Month
11/10/2014 12:00:00 AM  L   Current
11/9/2014 12:00:00 AM   H   Current
11/8/2014 12:00:00 AM   H   Current
11/7/2014 12:00:00 AM   L   Current
11/6/2014 12:00:00 AM   H   Current
11/5/2014 12:00:00 AM   H   Current
11/4/2014 12:00:00 AM   L   Current
```

I would like to loop through the records and get the no of TypeofLeaves="H" between consecutive TypeOfLeave="L"

How do I design my loop so that I get consecutive rows for TypeOfLeave="L"? Or is there a better way to do that without using loop to fetch next record?

Update:

Output required:

```
First  TypeofLeave ='L' - 11/10/2014 12:00:00 AM    L   Current
Next TypeOfleave='L' - 11/7/2014 12:00:00 AM    L   Current

So no of typeOfleave ='H' in between First and next =2

then,
first TypeOfleave='L' - 11/7/2014 12:00:00 AM   L   Current
next TypeOfleave='L' 11/4/2014 12:00:00 AM  L   Current

and no of typeOfleave ='H' in between First and next =2
```

Comment: Where do you stuck in your attempt?

Comment: I figured out the logic. Thanks u all for the input

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
DataRow[] result = dtAbsent.Select("TypeOfLeave = 'L'");

foreach (DataRow row in result) 
{   
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", row[0].ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: From OP: "I would like to loop through the records and get the no of TypeofLeaves="H" between consecutive TypeOfLeave="L""

Comment: Yes this will give me all the records with TypeOfLeave='L'; But I need consecutive records

Comment: I don't understant well what kind of output you want. Can you give me an example of output?